# Why do I have an error while trying to login sanity during setup?

Tags: reactjs, sanity

can someone help with this error from the terminal if i try to login? And my browser says The Site can't be reached Localhost refused to connect.

Opening browser at https://api.sanity.io/v1/auth/login/google?type=token&label=DESKTOP-1LRTS4A+%2F+Windows&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4321%2Fcallback

⠋ Waiting for browser login to complete... Press Ctrl + C to cancelError: spawn UNKNOWN
at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:413:11)
at Object.spawn (node:child_process:743:9)
at baseOpen (C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@sanity\cli\lib_chunks\cli-87ae38a9.js:13432:248) {
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'spawn'
}

I have tried to switch off my firewalls, proxy and flush my DNS to see if its a browser issue, and i also tried out opera asides using chrome and I still can't login